# How do you add date and time into database when submitting a form?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am trying to add date and time when an account is created when submitting the registration form.  I am trying this and it delivers: 0000-00-00 00:00:00

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (id, username, email, password, created) VALUES (NULL, '$username', '$email', '$password', now())") or die(mysql_error());
```

This is completely different than the duplicate answered question you are replacing it with..

Comment: Your `created` is varchar I'll bet, correct? Probably why you posted your own answer and using that format. If that's the case, then you could have altered it to be DATETIME type.

Comment: @Fred-ii Ya DATETIME i had but really all I needed to do was change it to TIMESTAMP..  Why did you mark it as duplicate?  It has nothing to do with that other question

Answer (score 0):

$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (id, username, email, password, created) VALUES (NULL, '$username', '$email', '$password', '$date')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: It's best to enter the raw time stamp into the database so you can format it how you like in as many different ways once retrieving it from the database

Comment: How do you do that?  How do you set it to a specific time zone too and not just the servers timezone?

Comment: I'll add it as an answer as I can't do a multi line comment

Answer (score 0):

Is it your fields ***DATETIME*** OR ***TIMESTAMP***?, be sure that it is one of them.

Also, if your field is ***TIMESTAMP*** you can set the default value as ***CURRENT_TIMESTAMP***

Comment: DATETIME..  I figured it out.. Answered it below..  Thanks

Comment: How do you set it to the current time zone and not server timezone?

Comment: If you're inserting from PHP, you can set the timezone: date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City'); if your using CURRENT_TIMESTAM as a default value, you can try this (I'm not sure if it work for default): $conexion->query('SET time_zone = \'-06:00\'');

Comment: Where do I put that?

Comment: The firts option (if you're getting the date with PHP), at the top of your PHP file. The second option (if you're getting the date with MySQL), it could be just after you create the conexion (preferably), or wherever before your INSERT query, but since you are using the old mysql mode, it should be like this: mysql_query('SET time_zone = "-06:00";')

Answer (score 0):

Before using now() function, make sure you have set your timezone and check by echoing wat it is printing before putting it into query directly.

Comment: This is setting to the servers time zone..  Works now cause I set it to TIMESTAMP.. Do you know how to set to specific timezone?

Comment: Yes, you can use this code at the top: date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Bangkok");  There are various timezone like this "Asia/Bangkok", you can find the list here: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Answer (score 0):

```
//insert raw time stamp into database
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (id, username, email, password, created) VALUES (NULL, '$username', '$email', '$password', '" . time() . "')") or die(mysql_error());

//get time stamp from database and format it
$user = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users where id = '1'");
if (mysql_num_rows($user)>0) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($user);
    echo 'Created: ', date('F jS Y - g:i a', $row['created']);
} else {
    echo 'User doesn\'t exist';
}
```

Take a look into [PHP's date function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), it takes 2 parameters. First being the format you want, second being the UNIX time stamp.

So if you enter the raw time stamp into the database, you can retrieve it as that and format it how you like when retrieving it.

On another note, take a look into PDO. `mysql_*` functions will soon be deprecated.

Comment: '" . time() . "'  is still showing all zeros when it enters the database..

Comment: @Jylaw38 what data type is your `created` field in your database?

Comment: I have it set to DATETIME

Comment: Set it to INTEGER with length value of 11

Comment: I changed it to TIMESTAMP and it works now

Comment: @Jylaw38 good stuff.